# magento 1.9 observer on quantity product change

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, event-observer

I can't find the event for quantity product change for magento 1.9.
I need to do something after a quantity product is updated from backend and frontend, when a user buy a product and decrease quantity, when a quantity is updated from admin page and when is updated from a script then programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Test_Testing>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </Test_Testing>
</modules>
<global>
    <events>
        <??>
            <observers>
                <test_testing_obs>
                    <class>Test_Testing/observer</class>
                    <method>move_products_category</method>
                </test_testing_obs>
            </observers>
        </??>
    </events>
</config>
```

Comment: what do you want to do when quantity decrease after place order?

Comment: I want to move a product to another category.

Answer (score 0):

You can used the following events for product qty is change.

1. catalog_product_save_after
2. sales_order_place_after.